# add elements from array into existing json object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Is there a similar method to array.push that one can use to inject a new node into a json object?

I have an endpoint that requires a payload with dynamic element names based on what is being passed in, so i need to scrape the array and insert it into the payload for the correct format.

Example of the end-result payload i need:

```js
{
  "fields": {
    "project": {
      "key": projectKey
    },
    "summary": summary,
    "description": description,
    "issuetype": {
      "name": issueType
    },
    "customfield_123456": "value1",
    "customfield_7890": "value2"
  }
}
```

This is the function in the controller that consumes the request body and attempts to inject the values in the customFields Array as elements in the json object but is not working:

```js
const createIssueApi = async(req, res, next) => {
  try {
    let {
      projectKey,
      summary,
      description,
      issueType,
      customFields
    } = req.body;
    console.log(req.body)

    let jiraIssue = {
      "fields": {
        "project": {
          "key": projectKey
        },
        "summary": summary,
        "description": description,
        "issuetype": {
          "name": issueType
        }
      }
    }

    for (let ix = 0; ix < customFields.length; ix++) {
      jiraIssue.fields[$ {
        customFields[ix]
      }] = customFields[ix];
    }
    console.log("Jira Issue payload: ", jiraIssue)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
  }
}
```

This is the payload being sent in:

```js
{
  "projectKey": "JK",
  "summary": "summary text",
  "description": "THIS IS JUST A TEST",
  "issueType": "Submit a request or incident",
  "customFields": [{
      "customfield_123456": "value1"
    },
    {
      "customfield_7890": "value2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: JSON.parse and JSON.stringify can help you here: first parse the JSON into an object, manipulate the object as you need, then convert it back to JSON

Comment: Is the console log different than what is being sent?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) and [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) inside `for`

```js
const customFields = [{
    'customfield_123456': 'value1'
  },
  {
    'customfield_7890': 'value2'
  }
];

const jiraIssue = {'fields': {}};

for (let ix = 0; ix < customFields.length; ix++) {
  for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(customFields[ix])) {
    jiraIssue.fields[key] = val;
  }
}

console.log(jiraIssue);
```

The following is an example used with [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const restructure = (req) => {
  const {customFields, ...rest} = req.body;
  const fields = {
    'project': {
      "key": rest['projectKey']
    },
    'summary': rest['summary'],
    'description': rest['description'],
    'issuetype': {
      "name": rest['issueType']
    }
  };
  customFields.reduce((accumu, current) => {
    for (const [key, val] of Object.entries(current)) {
      accumu[key] = val;
    }
    return accumu;
  }, fields);
  return {fields};
}

const req = {
  "body": {
    "projectKey": "JK",
    "summary": "summary text",
    "description": "THIS IS JUST A TEST",
    "issueType": "Submit a request or incident",
    "customFields": [{
        "customfield_123456": "value1"
      },
      {
        "customfield_7890": "value2"
      }
    ]
  }
};

console.log(restructure(req));
```

Comment: May as well use [`Object.fromEntries()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries) if you're using `Object.entries()`

Answer (score 0):

there are methods

```
 Array.prototype.push()
    
    Array.prototype.pop()
    Array.prototype.shift()
    Array.prototype.unshift()
    Array.prototype.concat()
```

for instance

```
const animals = ['pigs', 'goats', 'sheep'];

const count = animals.push('cows');
console.log(count);
// expected output: 4
console.log(animals);
// expected output: Array ["pigs", "goats", "sheep", "cows"]

animals.push('chickens', 'cats', 'dogs');
console.log(animals);
// expected output: Array ["pigs", "goats", "sheep", "cows", "chickens", "cats", "dogs"]
```

Comment: Not sure how this addresses the question

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be attempting to use the same value for both the name and the value, and your Js seems to be invalid in that spot - `[$ {` is not valid js, but something like this should work

```
jiraIssue.fields[`customFields_${ix}`] = customFields[ix];
```